# C# Parallel ForEach hold value

Tags: c#, foreach, parallel-processing, plinq

I am working on an app that searches for email addresses in Google search results' URLs. The problem is it needs to return the value it found in each page + the URL in which it found the email, to a datagridview with 2 columns: Email and URL.
I am using Parallel.ForEach for this one but of course it returns random URLs and not the ones it really found the email on.

```
public static string htmlcon;  //htmlsource

public static List<string> emailList = new List<string>();

public static string Get(string url, bool proxy)
    {
        htmlcon = "";

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            if (proxy)
                req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.UserAgent = Settings1.Default.UserAgent;
            if (Settings1.Default.EnableCookies == true)
            {
                CookieContainer cont = new CookieContainer();
                req.CookieContainer = cont;
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            htmlcon = SR.ReadToEnd();

            Thread.Sleep(400);
            resp.Close();
            SR.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        return htmlcon;

    }



  private void copyMails(string url)
    {    
        string emailPat = @"(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)";
        MatchCollection mailcol = Regex.Matches(htmlcon, emailPat, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match mailMatch in mailcol)
        {
            email = mailMatch.Groups[1].Value;
            if (!emailList.Contains(email))
            {
                emailList.Add(email);



                  Action dgeins = () => mailDataGrid.Rows.Insert(0, email, url);
                  mailDataGrid.BeginInvoke(dgeins);

             }
        }
     }

  private void SEbgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     //ALOT OF IRRELEVAMT STUFF BEING RUN

     Parallel.ForEach(allSElist.OfType<string>(), (s) =>
        {
            //Get URL
            Get(s, Settings1.Default.Proxyset);


            //match mails 1st page 
            copyMails(s);
            });

 }
```

so this is it: I execute a Get request(where "s" is the URL from the list) and then execute copyMails(s) from the URL's html source. It uses regex to copy the emails.
If I do it without parallel it returns the correct URL for each email in the datagridview. How can I do this parallel an still get the correct match in the datagridview?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please more clearly describe whats happening in copyValue. And am I right, you take URL from results page and make http request to this page to retrieve real URI, and its done in Get operation?

Comment: Basically the copyValue() reads the html that the GET returned and searches for the value in the html.

Comment: Most likely something is shared in these 2 methods among threads. When it's possible to show their implementation, then I can say more.

Comment: @Regfor OK Check out my post - I edited and put the entire relevant code..

Thanks Again!

Comment: To clarify: the "correct match" is between the order of URLs in the input `allSElist` and the list of emails in `mailDataGrid`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be better off using PLINQ's `Where` to filter (pseudo code):

```
var results = from i in input.AsParallel()
              let u = get the URL from i
              let d = get the data from u
              let v = try get the value from d
              where v is found
              select new {
                Url = u,
                Value = v
              };
```

Underneath the [`AsParallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel.aspx) means that TPL's implementation of [LINQ operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.aspx) (`Select`, `Where`, ...) is used.

---

***UPDATE: Now with more information***

**First** there are a number of issues in your code:

1. The variable `htmlcon` is `static` but used directly by multiple threads. This could well be your underlying problem. Consider just two input values. The first `Get` completes setting `htmlcon`, before that thread's call to `copyMails` starts the second thread's `Get` completes its HTML GET and writes to `htmlcon`. With `email
2. The list `emailList` is also accessed without locking by multiple threads. Most collection types in .NET (and any other programming platform) are *not* thread safe, you need to limit access to a single thread at a time.
3. You are mixing up various activities in each of your methods. Consider applying the singe responsibility principle.
4. `Thread.Sleep` to handle an exception?! If you can't handle an exception (ie. resolve the condition) then do nothing. In this case if the action throws then the `Parallel.Foreach` will throw: that'll do until you define how to handle the HTML GET failing.

Three suggestions:

1. In my experience clean code (to an obsessive degree) makes things easier: the details of the format
   don't matter (one true brace style is better, but consistency is the key). Just going through
   and cleaning up the formatting showed up issues #1 and #2.
2. Good naming. Don't abbreviate anything used over more than a few lines of code unless that is a 
   significant term for the domain. Eg. `s` for the action parameter in the parallel loop is really a url
   so call it that. This kind of thing immediately makes the code easier to follow.
3. Think about that regex for emails: there are many valid emails that will not match (eg. use of `+` to provide multiple logical addresses: `exmaple+one@gamil.com` will be delivered to `example@gmail.com` and can then be used for local rules). Also an apostrophe ("`'`") is a valid character (and known people frustrated by web sites that refused their addresses by getting this wrong).

**Second**: A relatively direct clean up:

```
public static string Get(string url, bool proxy) {

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (proxy) {
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort);
    }
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.UserAgent = Settings1.Default.UserAgent;
    if (Settings1.Default.EnableCookies == true) {
        CookieContainer cont = new CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer = cont;
    }
    using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
        return SR.ReadToEnd();
    }

}

private static Regex emailMatcher = new Regex(@"(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

private static string[] ExtractEmails(string htmlContent) {    

    return emailMatcher.Matches(htmlContent).OfType<Match>
                       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToArray();
 }

private void SEbgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

    Parallel.ForEach(allSElist.OfType<string>(), url => {
        var htmlContent = Get(url, Settings1.Default.Proxyset);
        var emails = ExtractEmails(htmlContent);

        foreach (var email in emails) {
            Action dgeins = () => mailDataGrid.Rows.Insert(0, email, url);
            mailDataGrid.BeginInvoke(dgeins);
        }
}
```

Here I have:

- Made use of `using` statements to automate the cleanup of resources.
- Eliminated all mutable shared state.
- `Regex` is explicitly documented to have thread safe instance methods. So I only need a single instance.
- Removed noise: no need to pass the URL to `ExtractEmails` because the extraction doesn't use the URL.
- `Get` now only performs the HTML get, `ExtreactEMail` just the extraction

**Third**: The above will block threads on the slowest operation: the HTML GET.

The real concurrency benefit would be to replace `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` and reading the response stream with their asynchronous equivalents.

Using `Task` would be the answer in .NET 4, but you need to directly work with `Stream` and encoding yourself because `StreamReader` doesn't provide any `BeginABC`/`EndABC` method pairs. But .NET 4.5 is almost here, so apply some `async`/`await`:

- Nothing to do in `ExtractEMails`.
- `Get` is now asynchronous, blocking in neither the HTTP GET or reading the result.
- `SEbgWorker_DoWork` uses Tasks directly to avoid mixing too many different ways to work with TPL. Since `Get` returns a `Task<string>` can simple continue (when it hasn't failed – unless you specify otherwise `ContinueWith` will only continue if the previous task has completed successfully):

This should work in .NET 4.5, but without a set of valid URLs for which this will work I cannot test.

```
public static async Task<string> Get(string url, bool proxy) {

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (proxy) {
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort);
    }
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.UserAgent = Settings1.Default.UserAgent;
    if (Settings1.Default.EnableCookies == true) {
        CookieContainer cont = new CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer = cont;
    }
    using (WebResponse resp = await req.GetResponseAsync())
    using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
        return await SR.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

}

private static Regex emailMatcher = new Regex(@"(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

private static string[] ExtractEmails(string htmlContent) {    

    return emailMatcher.Matches(htmlContent).OfType<Match>
                       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToArray();
 }

private void SEbgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

    tasks = allSElist.OfType<string>()
                     .Select(url => {
        return Get(url, Settings1.Default.Proxyset)
                .ContinueWith(htmlContentTask => {
                    // No TaskContinuationOptions, so know always OK here
                    var htmlContent = htmlContentTask.Result;
                    var emails = ExtractEmails(htmlContent);
                    foreach (var email in emails) {
                        // No InvokeAsync on WinForms, so do this the old way.
                        Action dgeins = () => mailDataGrid.Rows.Insert(0, email, url);
                        mailDataGrid.BeginInvoke(dgeins);
                    }
                });
    });

    tasks.WaitAll();
}
```

Comment: Tried but couldn't implement..
I need "u" to be the s in list<string>
"d" = get(s)
"v" = email from copyValue()
and then on I cant figure it out.. just doesnt work

Comment: @Zbone Please define what `u` etc. are (not their type) but there use. Perhaps expanding on how a single element in `allSElist` would be processed would allow me to translate more effectively. I'm assuming your problem is that the action passed to `Parallel.For` doesn't return a value so you're trying to build you own result collection. Rather than treating it as a filter & transform process.

Comment: Actually it does return the value. The problem is that when I use Parallel.Foreach instead of regular foreach, I get the value matched to the wrong URL. When I use the regular foreach the matching is correct. Please see that method "copyValue(s)" takes the url as a parameter so that when it finds the value it connects it to the URL. Parallel makes it connect to a random URL rather than to the correct URL's source in which it found that value.
THANKS!

Comment: @Zbone I mean the `Parallel.Foreach` doesn't use a `Func<TInput,TResult>` and thus return a collection of results from the calls to the body. If data values are not matching up then you are not keeping them together. Note the way my code returns an object (of anonymous type, but it can be a specifically defined type or a `Tuple`) that brings together all the data you want out. But I repeat, for me to be more specific you are going to need to be more specific.

Comment: OK Check out my post - I edited and put the entire relevant code..

Thanks Again!

Comment: If my clarification (see comment on Q) is correct then your problem is you are assuming that tasks performed in parallel will complete in the order of the input. This is explicitly never going to be the case. To maximise performance the input is chunked up and, of course, each body can take a different amount of time to complete. You need to assume ordering will be lost and thus re-order things at the end – in my pseudo code I do this by passing the input through the process and keeping it together with the output.

Comment: OK I see.. I understand PLINQ is the right way to go here but still can't understand how to implement it with the Get() and copyMails() (see the edited code I posted)
I would really appreciate an explanation based on my code. 

Thanks again

Comment: @Zbone: Quick answer: you can't. Separate the UI from the processing. Do not update the UI in `copyMails`, rather return the emails and the parallel process returns collection of {URL, array of email}. Then that is used to update the UI. (This update could be done as results complete, but start by keeping it easy.) I'll update this prototype a little later.

Comment: Epic answer, respect to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

> public static string htmlcon;  //htmlsource
>
> public static List emailList = new List();

**Problem is because these members htmlcon and emailList are shared resource among thread and among iterations.** Each your iteration in Parallel.ForEach is executed parallel. Thats why you have strange behaviour.

How to solve problem:

- Modify your code and try to implement it without static variables or shared state.

As an option is change from Parallel.ForEach to TPL Task chaining, when you make this change then result of one parallel operation will be input data for other and it's as an options among many how to modify code to avoid shared state.

- Use locking or concurrent collections. Your htmlcon variable could be made volatile but with list you should yous lock's or concurrent collections.

Better way is modify your code to avoid shared state, and how to do that are many options based on your implementation, not only task chaining.